# Display child terms in term taxonomy page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a vocabulary named "Catagory" with a term tree structure including parent and child taxonomy terms.

In every term's page I want to display all the child terms for that current term.
Terms are using alias. 
As far as I understand it can be acheived with views, but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Set up a new view of type "taxonomy terms"
- Give the view a "block" display (not a page)
- In the "advanced" section of the view (on the right) you can set up a "contextual filter" based on "parent term".
- The trick to making this work with a block is to select the "Provide default value" option and select "raw value from url" "path component 3". This will send in the id of the parent term from the url (works even though your term is aliased).
- Go to admin->blocks and put that block in the "footer" region; set it to only appear at the url taxonomy/term/* (this will work even though your term is aliased).